# Spring JNDI Configuration

Tags: spring, transactions, datasource, jndi, autocommit

We are using Spring to do JNDI look-up for our data access requirements. We are making calls to multiple stored procedures (in Sybase). I wanted a way to control the auto-commit property of the transactions while calling these stored procs. I was able to achieve it with BasicDataSource (property name="defaultAutoCommit").
But I got stuck when we moved to doing JNDI look-up (from Weblogic).

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="WL_data_source"  id="dataSource" />

<bean id="procedureHandlerBean" class="myclass">
    <property name="procDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

After researching for a few days, it appears to me that I can use JtaTransactionManager. However, I am not sure if I can use the transaction manager to configure auto-commit on a per procedure call basis (due to different chained/unchained mode requirements of different procs). Is there a clean way to achieve this? Thanks